# Displaying HTML String from Model in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a Model filed that returns an HTML string with line break BR tag, but How do I display that HTML on the browser ? The problem ins instead putting the line break, the Tag itself displaying on the UI

I tried to put the model within Html.Raw(modelItem => item.Speaking), but it never works as it expecting a string inside, and Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Below is the code and comments what I've tried.

```
<div>
  @{          
     string strTest = "<br/>Line 1 <br/> Line 2<br>";
     @Html.Raw(strTest); //This works and display as expected
     @MvcHtmlString.Create(strTest); //This works and display as expected       

     @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speaking)); //This doesn't work, its show the <br />  on the screen     
     @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speaking).ToString());   //This doent work, its show the <br />  on the screen  
     @Html.Raw(modelItem => item.Speaking) //This throw error Cannot convert lambda expression to type string                                     
    }

 </div>
```

Appreciate any help or suggestions. thanks in advance!

Comment: I have changed my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 15):

Try this :

```
@(new HtmlString(stringWithMarkup))
```

and you can create a HTML helper too!:

```
@helper RawText(string s) {
    @(new HtmlString(s))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Qualid for the response, but that didn't work. I want to know the way to pass the model value as a input to the HtmlString.     @(new HtmlString(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speaking).ToString())) This gives me the string with markup.

Comment: i just had to use :) Thanks people who took a look at the query!

    @Html.Raw(item.Speaking)

I got the answer from, http://forums.asp.net/p/2004322/5760921.aspx?p=True&t=635442239935208188&pagenum=1

Comment: It works with MVC 5, in case you just display the HTML content in a view.

Answer (score 9):

In **MVC4**

Instead of using  `@Html.Raw(modelItem => item.Speaking)`

You can use
`@Html.Raw(@Model.Speaking.ToString())`

It works for me and I hope this help someone else too

Comment: This is an old post but the above didn't work for me, but this did:  @HTML.Raw(item.Speaking.ToString()

Answer (score 6):

You can just omit both **DisplayFor** and **modelItem =>**,  so:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Speaking)
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC 5

```
@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Speaking))
```