# Asp.net mvc - how to show rich text without the html tags?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I DO NOT want to show the html tags in the content to the User. How to I do that?

---

I have a maintenance app that adds/edits blog content. It has a rich text editor.

[image]

When the content is saved in the SQL server database in a column defined as varchar(max), it saves it with html tags.

The edit feature retrieves it from the database and shows that:

[image]

Database:

[image]

Now when I want to display the content to the User in a view (.cshtml), I DO NOT want to see the html tags.

[image]

---

Here is the view (not showing all of the code):

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM

<h2 class="page-header"><span class="blogtitle">@Session["BlogTitle"]</span></h2>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}

@if (ViewBag.errormessage != null)
{
    <p class="alert alert-danger" id="errorMessage">@ViewBag.errormessage</p>
}

<br />

<div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("LoadDropdownBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished", "BlogPublished")">Return To Select a Blog</a>
</div>
<br />

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default toppanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent, new { @class = "form-control blogContent", @disabled = "disabled" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />

      
}
```

---

Here are the models (not showing all of the properties):

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM
    {
        public BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM()
        {
            this.BlogPublishedByBlogId = new BlogPublishedByBlogId();
        }

        public BlogPublishedByBlogId BlogPublishedByBlogId { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class BlogPublishedByBlogId
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Content")]
        public string BlogContent { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html Helper Raw will be use for your case.

```
@html.Raw("").
```

Comment: I tried: @Html.Raw(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent) but get: Cannot convert lamda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. I fi wrap it in quotes, then it just shows: model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent

Comment: I discovered and used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430648/displaying-html-string-from-model-in-mvc-razor-view ---->                     @Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent))

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@Html.Raw(Model.BlogContent)
```